# Magento OPC: How to enable auto complete of form fields?

Tags: magento, autocomplete

How do I enable the autocomplete for the form fields in the one page checkout area. Its not working out of the box and I guess thats because the OPC works with Ajax. I want to get suggestions for all data I inserted on my last order (name, company and so on) when I order again.

I tried adding autocomplete="on" and method="post" to the billing form, but that did not change a thing.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to either override the OPC Models that return data, or more likely the OPC templates themselves (to lookup previous order data and pre-fill). e.g /app/design/*package*/_theme_/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml